# Python 3 Equivalent for string.maketrans('','')

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the following snippet of Python 2 code to validate that the characters in `myStr` are printable characters:

```
import string

chars = string.maketrans('','')
badChars = chars.translate(chars, string.printable)
validStr = myStr.translate(chars, badChars)
```

In Python 2, the `maketrans()` line returns this:

```
>>> string.maketrans('','')
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

In Python 3, that same code returns an empty dictionary:

```
>>> str.maketrans('','')
{}
```

What is the Python 3 equivalent of `string.maketrans('','')`?

Comment: If all you need to know is whether the string is fully printable or not, you can simply call `chars.isprintable()`.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about what you expect `maketrans()` to return? The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) seem to indicate it returns a table based on the first two inputs - so your usage here is probably returning as expected. What do you want your translate table to look like - that is, what characters are you trying to fix?

Comment: The difference is that in Python 2, `string.translate` only takes 256-character strings as an argument, while in Python 3 it can accept a mapping to more efficiently accommodate Unicode strings.

Comment: What happened when you tried comparing the [documentation for the old function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.maketrans) to the [documentation for the new function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)?

Comment: Also, the new `str.translate` doesn't accept a separate argument for characters to delete - you set that up by mapping them to `None` in the table.

Comment: It's worth understanding that you don't get to "cheat" with text any more - characters are properly and correctly understood as Unicode characters, and one of the consequences there is that there are over a million of them rather than just 256. It seems like your *actual* question is "how do I filter non-printable characters out of a string?", which is *already* an XY problem compared to what you're asking, and might *still* be the wrong question to ask - because it depends on *why* you want to do this.

Comment: Karl - Yes, I want to filter non-printable characters out, so the string only has printable characters.  This is necessary step in order not to break the software receiving this string.  Also, the documentation for the old function doesn't make sense to me as I don't understand what passing '' for the 'from' and 'to' arguments is doing.

Comment: I tried using DYZ's suggestion with chars.isprintable().  I tried this:
`''.join(c for c in myStr if c.isprintable())`
but then found the characters \x80 through \xff are considered printable but I don't want them in my string.  With the Python 2 code, those got filtered out.  My final string in Python 3 needs to be identical to the Python 2 string.

Comment: Rather than saying printable, I've come to realize the appropriate thing to say is I want my string to only contain ASCII characters.  I don't want any unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is only defined for the lower-half values of a byte, that is to say from 0x00 to 0x7f. So an ASCII string will only contain bytes whose values is in this range.

```
all_ascii_string = (
    "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f"
    "\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f"
    "\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f"
    "\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f"
    "\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f"
    "\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f"
    "\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f"
    "\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f"
)

non_all_ascii_string = (
    "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f"
    "\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f"
    "\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f"
    "\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x87\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f"
    #                              ^
    "\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f"
    "\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f"
    "\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f"
    "\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f"
)


def check_string_is_ascii_only(s) -> bool:
    return not any(ord(char) >= 0x80 for char in s)


print(check_string_is_ascii_only(all_ascii_string))
print(check_string_is_ascii_only(non_all_ascii_string))
```

Comment: A clearer example would be : `non_all_ascii_string = "I like to eat soufflé"`, which is `encode("ascii", errors="backslashreplace")`'d into `b'I like to eat souffl\\xe9'`, 0xE9 being greater than 0x80.